# Capistrano deployment to a VPS failing

Tags: ssh, git, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano to deploy a Ruby on Rails app to a VPS running Ubuntu 11.10. However, whenever I run cap:deploy i get this error:

```
cd: 1: can't cd to /var/www/appname/releases
```

The VPS I'm using is Linode. Locally, I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.2 Lion.

Also, I'm using git, Passenger and Ngninx, although I don't think it makes a difference, I think it has to do with folder privileges and SSH more than anything.

Here's the deploy.rb

```
set :user, "name"
set :application, "appname"
set :domain,      "000.000.201.001"
set :repository,  "."
set :use_sudo,    true  
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/#{application}"
set :scm,         "none"
set :deploy_via, :copy
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
end

task :stop, :roles => :app do
  # Do nothing.
end

desc "Restart Application"
task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have to do something like "cap deploy:setup" to create the directory prior to deployment? Can you ssh into the box and see if the directory exists, and verify the permissions are compatible with the user capistrano is using?

Comment: that def helped, but now I'm getting this error: find: `/home/omar/apps/appname/releases/20120130213034/public/javascripts': No such file or directory

Comment: 1. cap deploy:setup 2. cap deploy:cold

Comment: #1 works, #2 fails

Answer (score 1):

Try add the following to deploy.rb:

```
before 'deploy:update', :create_release_folder
task :create_release_folder do  
  run "sudo mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/releases"
end
```